# How to train a Neural Network to play a pong game?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to understand this paper explaining how to train a Neural Network to play a pong game. 
https://cloud.github.com/downloads/inf0-warri0r/neural_pong/README.pdf

I have recently started studying neural network and I know the concept of Back Propagation. In this paper Back Propagation is used to train the neural network.

There are five input neurons in this neural network.

1. x coordinate of the ball (bx)
2. y coordinate of the ball (by)
3. velocity of the ball in x direction (bvx)
4. velocity of the ball in y direction (bvy)
5. Position of the paddle (py).

There are ten neurons in the hidden layer and one neuron in the output layer which will output the position of the paddle (py).

[image]

From this point onward I had some doubts to clear out.

As Back Propagation is a supervised learning method it should have some desired output from which we iteratively subtract the current output to find the error in the output and calculate the gradient descent.

1. Now what I don't understand is that what would be the desired output in this case. Can it be distance between the position where the ball hits the wall and the position of the paddle, which we should keep zero?
2. I know that the control paddle will be hard coded to move synchronously with the ball but how do we randomly move the other paddle while we are training it? What values should we give in the input "py"?
3. At what point in game all the five inputs bx,by,bvx, bvy and py should be provided? Should we give these inputs and perform one epoch of neural network iteration only when the ball hits the wall?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off I would like to dissuade you from using this paper as an educational tool. The code is poorly documented, and the paper itself isn't very informative.

1. In the code repository, he appears to use the output as the distance from the paddle to where it should be. He then trains the network based on the actual distance from the paddle to the ball whenever the paddle misses.
2. The original paper moves the opposing paddle by simply training two networks against each other. This has some drawbacks, but in this case shouldn't be an issue. The value for py appears to be the current paddle y coordinate
3. In the code he provides the network with the currents state of the game at every frame, and then allows them to choose a target distance to move to. He then trains the NNs whenever they miss the ball.

This design has some disadvantages. For example, you only get one data point to train it against for each ball, and since the ball is always at the edge of the game board when we collect this data point, we don't learn much about how to move when the ball is actually bouncing around the map.

I would recommend keeping track of all values given to the network as it plays. Later you can train the network using the original game states and the actual location that the ball ended up in. This way the network can be trained usefully even when it successfully blocks the ball, and it gains data from all points in the game.